# Deleting a podcast off of an iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch, podcasts

I downloaded a podcast directly to my iPod, decided I didn't want it, and now it will not go away. I can delete it from my iTunes library but the iPod just automatically copies it back in when I next sync it. I monkeyed with the podcast settings so only selected podcasts are synced on to the iPod, but it is still there (despite no longer appearing on the list in iTunes). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete it directly on your iPod.
It may be in the `Podcasts` app (`Downloads` tab) if the podcast's download is still not finished, or in the `Music` app (`Podcasts` tab). To delete a podcast, you just have to swipe left or right on it.

PS: Unfortunately, I don't know what iOS version do you have installed and I cannot comment to specify this, so I have written these tips for iOS 5.